# Convert image datatype from uint16 to uint8

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, image-processing, fiji

I have a tiff image stack in uint16 datatype and I’d like to convert this to uint8 datatype. I’m not sure how to do this in Fiji.

I have loaded the stack in Fiji and I tried to change the datatype while exporting. But I couldn’t find any tab in Fiji export options for specifying the datatype.

Suggestions on how to do this in Fiji or alternatively in Python/MATLAB will be really helpful.

Comment: Did you happen to know how many images the .tiff file is storing?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Yes ~500

Comment: Any chance you could post the image or a test image, I only have a 2 image .tiff on hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `im2uint8()` function can be used to convert the image from `uint16` (unsigned integer 16) to `uint8` (unsigned integer 8) in MATLAB.

### For .tiff Files with a Single Image :

```
Image = imread("Test_Image.tiff");
Image = im2uint8(Image);
imshow(Image);
```

### For .tiff Files with  Multiple Images and Saving Transformed/Converted Images:

Reading the images in a loop using the `imread()` function with second argument being the `Image_Index` corresponding to the image number within the .tiff image collection can be used to grab the entire image data stored in the file. Using `imwrite()` in `append` and `WriteMode` will allow each converted image to be saved into one file named in this example as `Converted_Image.tiff`.

```
%Multiple image tiff conversion%

File_Name = "Test_Image.tiff";
Image_Data = imfinfo(File_Name);
Number_Of_Images = length(Image_Data);


Tiff_Structure = struct('Image_File',[]);  

for Image_Index = 1: Number_Of_Images
    
      Image = imread(File_Name,Image_Index);
      Uint8_Image = im2uint8(Image);

      %For more information and plotting individual images%
      Tiff_Structure(Image_Index).Image_File = Uint8_Image;
      
      %Saving the converted images to one tiff file%
      imwrite(Uint8_Image,'Converted_Image.tiff','WriteMode','append');

end
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: Please find the image stack [here](https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/21659829?private_link=5091cb1b57c1e7cfa112). I tried the above and I could successfully view the converted image via imshow. But I see only the first image in the stack. Could you please have a look at the input image? I would also like to know how to save the stack after conversion.

Comment: @Natasha I edited the answer hopefully this suffices.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to plot the histogram(like [this](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/6074129eead9d8669f91b6323311b7f8fa0f442c.png)) of the `Image_Data` in MATLAB? I looked at imhist but I think it for a single image. I am not sure how to use this for multiple images in the stack. I'd also like to rescale the data before converting data types. Since in 16 bits it is occupying only a small amount of the available value range. Kindly let me know if I have to post this question in a new thread.

Comment: I'd say using `imhist()` on `Uint8_Image` within the loop would provide you with the histograms for each image within the stack. Also plotting multiple histograms/images can be done using `montage()` or `subplot()`.

Comment: The rescaling and exact plotting details may be best suited for a new question.

Comment: Sure. Could you please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438731/how-to-rescale-image-data-before-converting-data-types)?

Comment: Yeah, for sure. Will check it out soon. :)